# Can settings in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d be overridden from the command line with apt-get?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to override system-wide settings when installing packages with `apt-get --option`. For example, `snapper` will automatically create (2) snapshots whenever a package is updated/installed with apt. What I'd like to be able to do is from time to time, install a package or 2 without having snapshots created.

What I've tried so far was this:

```
sudo apt-get --option DPkg::Pre-Invoke="" --option DPkg::Post-Invoke="" install --reinstall grep
```

Basically tried to cancel both actions, but my commands were ignored. Is what I'm trying even doable? What about going in the other direction - i.e., removing the `snapper` file and using an alias to add the pre/post options as required?

Comment: You might be passing the wrong values to your option. Try instead `APT::Update::Pre-Invoke` etc. An Apt option clearly needs to be in the APT namespace. Check documentation.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - thanks for that info. The reason I used the options I did was because I copied them directly from the `snapper` settings in apt preferences.

Comment: If that works for you, you could close the question. Or I could write a short answer if you want, though I'm fairly fuzzy on the details of Apt command line usage myself.

Comment: So far the only thing I can get to work is to temporarily change the permissions of the config file to 000 so apt can't read it. For now, I'm going to change the setting permanently and revisit it at another time.

Answer (score 0):

(In Kubuntu since sometime in 2018) /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80snapper checks the DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT environment variable, and if set to "yes" does not do the snapper pre and post creates.

You could check your /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80snapper to see if it mentions DISABLE_APT_SNAPSHOT.